# java.io.InvalidClassException: Serializable incompatible with Externalizable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, serialization

What causes this exception in general?

I am working on a Java project with Maven. One of the libraries that I need has a class `SerializedObjects` that implements the `Serializable` interface. When I run my program, the above exception is thrown, which originated at the method `readObject` of the class.

Strangely, when I import the library manually in Eclipse the problem just disappears. I don't think there is a problem with my `pom.xml` because calling any other method from the same library not involving the `SerializedObject` class works just fine. The class has a `serialVersionUID` so I don't think that is the source of the problem.

I rely on `mvn:package` to deploy my project, so having this particular library not imported via maven seems inconvenient. Does anybody have similar problem in the past?

EDIT since I was asked a code snippet:

```
public static <T> T readObject(final String inputFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return SerializedObjects.<T>readObject(new InputSupplier<ObjectInputStream>() {
        @Override public ObjectInputStream getInput() throws IOException {
            return getObjectInputStream(inputFile);
        } });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T readObject(InputSupplier<ObjectInputStream> inputSupplier)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final ObjectInputStream input = inputSupplier.getInput();
    try{
        return (T) input.readObject(); // <-- exception here
    } finally{
        closeQuietly(input);
    }
}
```

Exception originated on `return (T) input.readObject();` and then continued up as follow:

```
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:628)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
```

EDIT 2, my `pom.xml` explicitly asks for eclipse compiler:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I guess this error also occur when packages are different at the time of serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: Paste code snippet please.

Comment: @Nidhi257 What possibly causes the packages to be different? Is it somehow related to the use of Maven?

Comment: You know that Eclipse uses a different compiler than Maven (unless explicitly configured)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I did explicitly configure that but it does not solve the problem. Added the snippet. Maybe I did something wrong?